# Is there a way to create a cross filter chart on columns with an 'object' data types in AG Grid?

Tags: ag-grid

I am currently trying to build a graph similar to [this one](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/integrated-charts-api-cross-filter-chart/).

The only difference is that one of column data type is a 'complex' object in the form of `{ id: string, name: string }`. For the grid itself and the filter, it is possible to pass `valueParser` and `valueFormatter` in the column definition to display and parse correctly the data.

However for charts, I can't seem to find any equivalent.

Here is what I already tried:

```
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
import React, { useCallback, useMemo, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import 'ag-grid-enterprise';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';
import {
  AgChartThemeOverrides,
  ColDef,
  ColGroupDef,
  FirstDataRenderedEvent,
  Grid,
  GridApi,
  GridOptions,
} from 'ag-grid-community';

const names = [
  'Aden Moreno',
  'Alton Watson',
  'Caleb Scott',
  'Cathy Wilkins',
  'Charlie Dodd',
  'Jermaine Price',
  'Reis Vasquez',
];

const phones = [
  { id: 'huawei', handset: 'Huawei P40', price: 599 },
  { id: 'pixel', handset: 'Google Pixel 5', price: 589 },
  { id: 'iphone', handset: 'Apple iPhone 12', price: 849 },
  { id: 'samsung', handset: 'Samsung Galaxy S10', price: 499 },
  { id: 'motorola', handset: 'Motorola Edge', price: 549 },
  { id: 'sony', handset: 'Sony Xperia', price: 279 },
];

export function getData(): any[] {
  const data: any[] = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    const phone = phones[getRandomNumber(0, phones.length)];
    const saleDate = randomDate(new Date(2020, 0, 1), new Date(2020, 11, 31));
    const quarter = 'Q' + Math.floor((saleDate.getMonth() + 3) / 3);

    data.push({
      salesRep: names[getRandomNumber(0, names.length)],
      handset: phone,
      sale: phone.price,
      saleDate,
      quarter,
    });
  }

  data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.saleDate.getTime() - b.saleDate.getTime();
  });

  data.forEach(function (d) {
    d.saleDate = d.saleDate.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
  });

  return data;
}

function getRandomNumber(min: number, max: number) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

function randomDate(start: Date, end: Date) {
  return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
}

function createHandsetSalesChart(gridApi: GridApi) {
  gridApi.createCrossFilterChart({
    chartType: 'area',
    cellRange: {
      columns: ['handset', 'sale'],
    },
    aggFunc: 'count',
    chartThemeOverrides: {
      common: {
        title: {
          enabled: true,
          text: 'Handsets Sold (Units)',
        },
      },
    },
    chartContainer: (document.querySelector('#areaChart') as HTMLElement) ?? undefined,
  });
}

export default function ExampleChart() {
  const containerStyle = useMemo(() => ({ width: '100%', height: '100%' }), []);
  const gridStyle = useMemo(() => ({ height: '100%', width: '100%' }), []);
  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState<any[]>(getData());
  const [columnDefs, setColumnDefs] = useState<ColDef[]>([
    { field: 'salesRep', chartDataType: 'category' },
    {
      field: 'handset',
      valueParser: (params) => {
        const item = phones.find((phone) => phone.handset === params.newValue);
        return item;
      },
      valueFormatter: (params) => {
        console.log(params);
        return params.value == null ? '' : params.value.handset;
      },
      keyCreator: (params: any) => params.value.handset,
      filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
      filterParams: {
        valueParser: (params: any) => {
          const item = phones.find((phone) => phone.handset === params.newValue);
          return item;
        },
        valueFormatter: (params: any) => {
          console.log(params);
          return params.value == null ? '' : params.value.handset;
        },
        keyCreator: (params: any) => params.value.id,
      },
      chartDataType: 'category',
    },
    {
      headerName: 'Sale Price',
      field: 'sale',
      maxWidth: 160,
      aggFunc: 'sum',
      filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter',
      chartDataType: 'series',
    },
    { field: 'saleDate', chartDataType: 'category' },
    {
      field: 'quarter',
      maxWidth: 160,
      filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
      chartDataType: 'category',
    },
  ]);
  const defaultColDef = useMemo<ColDef>(() => {
    return {
      flex: 1,
      editable: true,
      sortable: true,
      filter: 'agMultiColumnFilter',
      floatingFilter: true,
      resizable: true,
    };
  }, []);
  const chartThemes = useMemo<string[]>(() => {
    return ['ag-default-dark'];
  }, []);
  const chartThemeOverrides = useMemo<AgChartThemeOverrides>(() => {
    return {
      cartesian: {
        axes: {
          category: {
            label: {
              rotation: 0,
            },
          },
        },
      },
    };
  }, []);

  const onFirstDataRendered = useCallback((params: FirstDataRenderedEvent) => {
    createHandsetSalesChart(params.api);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={containerStyle}>
      <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="top">
          <div id="lineChart" className="ag-theme-alpine-dark h-72"></div>
          <div id="doughnutChart" className="ag-theme-alpine-dark h-72"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="areaChart" className="ag-theme-alpine-dark h-72"></div>

        <div className="ag-theme-alpine-dark h-72">
          <AgGridReact
            rowData={rowData}
            columnDefs={columnDefs}
            defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
            enableCharts={true}
            chartThemes={chartThemes}
            chartThemeOverrides={chartThemeOverrides}
            onFirstDataRendered={onFirstDataRendered}
          ></AgGridReact>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the [visual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEIXl.png), note the [object Object] instead of the phone names.